# Todolist на javascript, что исправить?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```js
/*Функция которая проверяет поле ввода, и запускает соответствующею функции если все ок*/
document.querySelector('.add-todo').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var field = document.querySelector('.field-todo');

  if (field.value && field.value !== ' ') {
    addTodo(field);
    field.value = '';
  }
});

document.querySelector('.field-todo').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && this.value && this.value !== ' ') {
    addTodo(this);
    this.value = '';
  }
});

//Очистка значения поля по клику
document.querySelector('.clean-value').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var field = document.querySelector('.field-todo');

  field.value = '';
});

//Функция добавления списка
function addTodo(field) {

  var fieldValue = field.value;
  var todoList = document.querySelector('.todo');

  var elements = {
    li: document.createElement('li'),
    buttonsWrap: document.createElement('div'),
    addCheck: document.createElement('a'),
    deleteTodo: document.createElement('a'),
    faCheck: document.createElement('i'),
    faTrash: document.createElement('i'),
  };

  //Присваиваем элементам нужные классы
  elements.buttonsWrap.classList.add('buttons');
  elements.addCheck.classList.add('add-check');
  elements.deleteTodo.classList.add('delete-todo');
  elements.faCheck.classList.add('fa', 'fa-check');
  elements.faTrash.classList.add('fa', 'fa-trash');

  //Добавляем элементы в нужные теги
  elements.addCheck.appendChild(elements.faCheck);
  elements.deleteTodo.appendChild(elements.faTrash);

  elements.buttonsWrap.appendChild(elements.addCheck);
  elements.buttonsWrap.appendChild(elements.deleteTodo);

  elements.li.innerHTML = elements.li.innerHTML + fieldValue;
  elements.li.appendChild(elements.buttonsWrap);

  todoList.insertBefore(elements.li, todoList.firstChild);




  document.querySelector('.delete-todo').addEventListener('click', deleteTodo);
  document.querySelector('.add-check').addEventListener('click', completeTodo);
}

//Функция выполненния задачи
function completeTodo() {
  this.closest('li').classList.toggle('fill');
  allCheckList();
}

//Функция удаления списка
function deleteTodo() {
  this.closest('li').remove();
  allCheckList();
}

function allCheckList() {
  var allCheckElement = document.querySelectorAll('.fill');
  var countElement = document.querySelector('.count');

  countElement.innerHTML = allCheckElement.length;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #2D936C;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  margin: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"] {
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 0;
  text-indent: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:-moz-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 820px;
}

.main-header {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.main-header input {
  padding-right: 100px;
}


/*Buttons add todo && clean value*/

.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.buttons a {
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-right: 11px;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttons a:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.fa:hover {
  color: #000;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}


/*Style todo list*/

.todo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.todo li {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px 120px 20px 20px;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 9px #143a2b;
}

.todo .fa {
  color: #2D936C;
}

.todo li.fill {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.todo li.fill i.fa-check {
  color: #000;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.todo .fa:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.todo .buttons {
  right: 20px;
}

.todo .buttons a {
  border-color: #2D936C;
}

.count {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ef3486ccf2.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
    <header class="main-header">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter you activity..." class="field-todo">
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#" class="add-todo"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="clean-value"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <ul class="todo"></ul>
    <span class="count">0</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Здравствуйте. Создал такой todolist на чистом javascript.
Над версткой я сильно не заморачивался. Хотел бы узнать ваше мнение конкретно по поводу того как я реализовал все это на js, где есть ошибки или может есть способ лучше как это все сделать. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Для обучающего задания пойдет. Если же Вы целитесь в серьезную разработку, то навскидку:
1. Учитесь разделять ответственность в программе. Вот у вас есть функция addTodo которая а). Делаем это б). Делаем то с). Делаем еще это. Почему бы вот эти а) б) с) не сделать отдельными функциями? Если придется кучу данных между ними прокидывать - вот уже и класс нарисуется.
2. Все в глобальной области видимости - нехорошо, совсем нехорошо. В люом более-менее серьезном проекте любая лишняя штука в глобал скоупе может ударить тебя в спину.
3. es-6 синтаксис сейчас стандарт де факто

Comment: В общем код явно выдает студента/человека начинающего вникать в тему. В этом случае оно норм, но небольшого усложнения приложения этот набросок может не пережить. Например у вас не отделены данные от представления, по сути все данные хранятся в dom и за ними надо каждый раз туда обратно лезть.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму спасибо за совет, вот я немного изменил код https://jsfiddle.net/yf581z6b/1/

Comment: Нужно понимать что надо повесить выполнение js на какое-то раузмное событие, document.onload например, потмоу что никто не гарантирует что к моменту как js начнет работать, дом уже будет готов. Соответственно если дом готов не будет, ваш код работающий с дом честно упадет. Здесь все работает потому что jsfiddle добавляет эту обертку по умолчанию автоматически, может так оно вами задумано, может и нет, упомянуть не лишне

Comment: Ладно, вынос из глобал скоупа со скрипом засчитан Теперь попробуйте отделить данные от представления. Для того чтобы понять зачем это надо например попробуйте сделать автоматическое сохранение тудушек вводимых юзером в локалсторадж или еще куда, и загрузку оттуда соответственно.

Comment: На stackoverflow задают вопросы, если что-то неясно, а здесь всё отлично рабоает